# Getting TypeError when recreating Lodash dropWhile() method in Javascript for an assignment

Tags: lodash

I get the error: "TypeError: arrayslice is not a function" in "const droppedArray = array.slice(n)" when my dropWhile() method calls the drop() method (below).

I'm confident that the dropWhile() method is correct - so no changes needed here.

I've tried problem solving the TypeError in the drop() method and reworking the code - but keep going in circles with this - can you tell me what is going wrong and how to fix this? I'm sure it's something simple...

```
drop: function(array,n){
    if( n ===undefined){
      var n = 1;
    }
    const droppedArray = array.slice(n);
    return droppedArray;
},

dropWhile: function(array,predicate){
  const dropNumber = array.findIndex(function(element, index){
    return !predicate(element, index, array)
  });

  const dropArray = this.drop(dropNumber); 
  return dropArray; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to pass the array in your `drop` function:

```
const dropArray = drop(dropNumber);   // <-- missing the array param
```

Should be:

```
const dropArray = drop(array, dropNumber);
```

What happens now is your drop function is trying to call `slice` on the index found by this row:

```
const dropNumber = array.findIndex(function(element, index){
```

[Here is a fiddle to illustrate](https://jsfiddle.net/akrion/1ovp9Lc4/205/)